# Integration Runtime out of memory ADF

Tags: azure, out-of-memory, azure-data-factory

I am using data flow activity to convert MongoDB data to SQL.
As of now MongoDB/Atlas is not supported as a source in dataflow. I am converting MongoDB data to JSON file in AzureBlob Storage and then using that json file as a source in dataflow.

for a json source file whose size is around/more than 4Gb, whenever I try to import projection, the Azure Integration Runtime is throwing following error.
I have changed the core size to 16+16 and cluster type to memory optimized.

[image]

Is there any other way to import projection ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workaround for this was:
Instead of pulling all the data from mongo in a single blob, I pulled small chunks (500MB-1GB each) by using limit and skip option in "Copy Data" Activity.

and stored them in different JSON blobs

Answer (score 1):

Since your source data is one large file that contains lots of rows with maybe complex schemas, you can create a temporary file with a few rows that contain all the columns you want to read, and then do the following:

**1.** From the **data flow source Debug Settings** -> Import projection
with **sample file** to get the complete schema.

[image]

Now, **Select Import projection**.

**2.** Next, rollback the Debug Settings to use the source dataset for the remaining data movement/transformation.

If you want to map data types as well, you can follow this official MS [recommendation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-troubleshoot-connector-format#recommendation-2) doc, as map data type cannot be directly supported in JSON source.

Comment: I was trying something similar, but some of the json docs dont have the all the required fields we have in our model. hence its kind of trial and error way to see if the records of sample file covers all the fields.